# Converting a .getTime value for from date to Calender date of the format YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: javascript, gettime

I am trying to convert a .getTime date/value back to a format of the form YYY-MM-DD.
Any help on this please?

Currently I am populating my text From date with a value 2013-05-23. the .getTime value for this is 1371970800000 I then want to increment this .getTime value by 1371970800001, which is and auto populate the todate field with this incremented value in the calender format.
Any help on this is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectedDate = new Date("2013-05-23").getTime();
var nextDay = new Date(selectedDate + 86400000); // 86400000 - one day in ms 

nextDay.getFullYear(); // returns year
nextDay.getMonth(); // returns month
nextDay.getDate(); // returns day
```

you can do a concat to get the desired format